# SQL join query with appended columns

Tags: sql-server

I have the below SQL Server tables:

**Asset Table**

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| AssetID | AssetName | LocationID |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

**Location Table**

```
+-------------+---------------+------------------+
|  LocationID |  LocationName |  SubLocationName |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+
```

How can I return results where the Assets Table LocationID = Location Table LocationID but also append the corresponding
LocationName and SubLocationName as extra columns?

**Assets Table**

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| AssetID | AssetName | LocationID |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 | Asset1    |        123 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

**Location Table**

```
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| LocationID | LocationName       | SubLocationName      |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|        123 | Area1              | Sub1                 |
+------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

would return:

```
+--------+-------+------+
| Asset1 | Area1 | Sub1 |
+--------+-------+------+
```

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Have you tried inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT a.AssetID,a.AssetName,l.LocationName, l.SubLocationName
    FROM   Assets a
    JOIN   Location l ON a.LocationId = l.LocationId
```

Comment: Thanks piraji. Your query is exactly what I required. Paul.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables and query the columns you're interested in:

```
SELECT AssetName, LocationName, SubLocationName
FROM   Assets a
JOIN   Location l ON a.LocationId = l.LocationId
```

Comment: Mureinik, thanks for the reply. If I use the query I get 'invalid column name SubLocationName'. If I remove SubLocationName from the query it runs but returns 0 rows?

Comment: that means you do not have data in your table which match the records or by mistake you have selected different database. please verify once